# php simple dom parser get parent of element

Tags: php, jquery, html, simple-html-dom

I am trying to retrieve the img SRC on some DIV's with no discerning class or parents: They simply exist on the page after `<div class="content_end"></div>`

I need to retrieve the image `scr` from these `div's` how can I only retrieve only these div's and not all other div's on the page:

I tried doing finding all images with div as the parent but that didnt work:

```
foreach($domParse->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->parent('div')->src;
```

I know in jquery there's a nextAll selector so i'm able to do something like:

```
$('.content_end').nextAll('div');
```

which returns to me the content I need: How can I do this in Simple Dom Parser:

### HTML FORMAT

```
<div class="content_end"> </div>
-------------------------------------------------
<div style="postion:relative; height:90px;">
<img src="../">
</div>
<div style="postion:relative; height:90px;">
<img src="../">
</div>
---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Maybe you could try ``->find('div.content_end img')``?

Comment: @jreuab the images are not inside of '<div class="content_end></div>' that will return to me an empty set

Comment: Okay, so the images are in the div right after div.content_end?

Comment: since your'e targeting img tags which has a parent div with no class or id just use an attribute filter with the parent `!class` attribute filter

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is `next_sibling()`:

```
foreach($domParse->find('div.content_end') as $element) 
   echo $element->next_sibling()->find("img")[0]->src;
```

Comment: not quite working getting:  `call to memeber function find() on a non-object` meaning ->next_sibling() is returning nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Since your'e targeting `<img>` tags which has a parent div with **no** class or id just use an attribute filter with the parent `!class` **attribute filter**. Consider this example:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html_string = '
<div class="content_end"></div>
<div style="postion:relative; height:90px;">
    <img src="http://www.google.com/image1.jpg" />
</div>
<div style="postion:relative; height:90px;">
    <img src="http://www.stackoverflow.com/image2.png" />
</div>'; // your sample html structure
$domParse = str_get_html($html_string);

// div which has no class with img tag children
foreach($domParse->find('div[!class] img') as $img) {
    echo $img->src . '<br/>';
}
```

Should yield with as per example:

```
http://www.google.com/image1.jpg
http://www.stackoverflow.com/image2.png
```